# starting the locomotive.js application using nodemon

Tags: node.js, locomotivejs, nodemon

I've built an application using the [Locomotive.JS](http://locomotivejs.org/) MVC framework for node (locomotive is built upon express) , i wanted know how to start this application using nodemon??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [this blog post](http://artpluscode.com/blog/?p=162), if you don't already have a server.js, you need to create one to run your application, in order to use nodemon.

In the project directory, create a server.js file:

```
var locomotive = require('locomotive'),
        env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
        port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
        address = '0.0.0.0';

locomotive.boot(__dirname, env, function(err, server) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    server.listen(port, address, function() {
      var addr = this.address();
      console.log('listening on %s:%d', addr.address, addr.port);
    });
});
```

Then simply run:

```
nodemon server.js
```